# Why isn't AVAudioPlayer found after upgrading to iPhone SDK 4.0?

Tags: iphone, xcode

This is a simple problem, but it is proving surprisingly intractable for me.

As part of beginning to learn iPhone programming, I have written a few small programs and also entered some from a couple of books.  These apps worked fine until the other day when I downloaded and installed the latest development software from Apple.  Now my existing projects cannot find the AVAudioPlayer references.  Specifically, I get the following error message at link time:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-AVAudioPlayer in SpotOnGameViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have so far tried the following:
Edited the Project "Base SDK" setting -- which was missing any value after the upgrade -- to be "iPhone Simulator 4.0."
Edited the path of the AVFoundation framework to point to a known location.  When that didn't work, I deleted and re-added AVFoundation to the project.
Added an import for  after the one for 
Created a new test project with an AVAudioPlayer.  (This project got the same error.)

"Framework Search Paths" and "Library Search Paths" are both empty in my project settings. There does not appear to be a "project.pbxproj" file in any of my project folders.

Any further suggestions?